# Meaning of sympathetic to an object or concept

Tags: meaning

I get this example from the definition of 'Sympathetic' while I was studying the meaning of the word:

> She is sympathetic to the project.

(the link for the example: [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sympathetic))

What is the difference between the above sentence and the below one using 'favor'?

> She is in favor of the project.

Does the first sentence convey the feeling of sympathy?

For example, she thinks that the project is not excellent but she feels some connection or painful memory with the project and she considers giving more score to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many words have different meanings.

The sentence that you quote is given as an example of the specific meaning "to look upon with favor."

Therefore

> She is sympathetic to the project

**MEANS**

> She favors the project.

There is no need to try to mingle this use with other meanings of "sympathetic."